# Ruby : %w performance

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance

perhaps a simple question, but we are discussing about whether it better to use this snipper:

```
if %w(production staging).include?(Rails.env)
```

versus

```
if ["production","staging"].include?(Rails.env)
```

We just want to understand which is the most performant way, ignoring the sytax suggering from Ruby. From what I could on the web, the %w literal seems to be a shorthand to string.split on the provided whitespace string.

But which one is actually the fastest?

p.s : A source for the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: apparently you dont either if you can just comment like this.
We're dealing with portals here that handle a large simultanious user load, so I don't see the problem you have with me asking this question

Comment: You have worse performance issues somewhere else. Like, I don't know, database? It makes more sense spending time fixing those.

Comment: Shees. Stackoverflow is to post questions, no?
We want to know this question. Our database is fully clustered etc with clustered webservers and what not.
We are meeting our demands and everything, we are just curious about this tidbit, how hard is this

Comment: Curiosity is good. I just think that this code does not need to be optimized for performance. It needs to be optimized for readability. Performance differences are negligible.

Comment: That's why I said in the question to ignore the ruby suggering syntax. I know %w is alot more readable then the array literal in place.
We want to satisfy our curiosity as to what results are produced. All examples on Rubydoc and blogs tell you to use the %w shorthand. But not a single source tells you WHY this needs to be done or what the consequences are for using this above the old fashined array initializer

Comment: Well, if you're really that curious, you could look in the interpreter source. Or benchmark it. Or wait for someone else to come with an answer. Good luck with that :)

Comment: `if Rails.env == 'production' || Rails.env == 'staging'`. Though in the very unlikely event this is where you need to focus your optimizations, maybe you should define two boolean global variables `$production` and `$staging` in your initializers?

Comment: I totally agree with Sergio that if you have performance issues, they're somewhere else. Anyway, if you're really curious, [Benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) is your friend. I bet `%w` is slower, but you can check it yourself in a few minutes with a simple benchmark.

Comment: @LarsHaugseth, @NekoNova: By the way, `Rails.env` is no simple string. You can do `if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?` and avoid temp array.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The implementation of this relies on `method_missing` though, which is also expensive, just in a different way.

Comment: Sergio, if we now get a question about the performance of [`ActiveSupport::StringInquirer`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/StringInquirer), it's your fault :)

Comment: I'll behave and not ask that question :P

Comment: NekoNova, I'm not really against that kind of questions. You could have done the benchmarking yourself, but the answer from Michael Kohl make such questions worth asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what `%w` and `%W` do, taken directly from `parse.y` (with ommissions):

```
case '%':
[snip]
  switch (c) {
    [snip]
    case 'W':
      lex_strterm = NEW_STRTERM(str_dword, term, paren);
      do {c = nextc();} while (ISSPACE(c));
      pushback(c);
      return tWORDS_BEG;

    case 'w':
      lex_strterm = NEW_STRTERM(str_sword, term, paren);
      do {c = nextc();} while (ISSPACE(c));
      pushback(c);
      return tQWORDS_BEG;
```

Considering it's implemented on the parser level, I wouldn't worry too much about the performance.

Answer (score 3):

I've done some test on my c2d:

```
ruby -e "10000000.times { ['one', 'two'].include?('two')}"  
8.04s user 0.05s system 90% cpu 8.912 total

ruby -e "10000000.times { %w(one two).include?('two')}"  
8.03s user 0.05s system 93% cpu 8.608 total
```

Comment: 1.9.3-p125 :002 > require 'benchmark'
 => true 
1.9.3-p125 :003 > puts Benchmark.measure{ 1000000.times do ["production","staging"].include?("staging") end}
  0.970000   0.000000   0.970000 (  0.976099)
 => nil 
1.9.3-p125 :004 > puts Benchmark.measure {1000000.times do %w(production staging).include?("staging") end}
  0.970000   0.000000   0.970000 (  0.973253)
 => nil 

is my result. Seems %w is faster :S

Comment: Firstly, you should drop the call to `include?` here, as it should take the exact same amount of time in both cases, being called on an array of two strings. Secondly, when I run both of these several times, the variation between the two cases are less than the variation between different runs of the same case.

Comment: reran the test without the include. Getting indeed the results you descibed.